# unable to close an unexpected ad on the website

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login to the website using Selenium Webdriver. But "http://www.letskodeit.com/" when I am opening this site an ad is popping up. I am unable to close the the ad. I need help to sort it out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my example of the method for closing your banner:

```java
public static void closeAd(WebDriver driver){
    Wait adWaiter = new FluentWait(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    WebElement closeButton = (WebElement) adWaiter.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        @Override
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver o) {
            return o.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@role='button'][@title='Back to site']"));
        }
    });
    closeButton.click();
    System.out.println("Banner closed..");
}
```

And here is the example that is showing that the method is working fine:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/Dev/WebDrivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
    driver1.get("http://www.letskodeit.com/");
    closeAd(driver1);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver1.quit();
}
```

I added `Thread.sleep(10000)` at the end just to make the test more representative.

**P.S.** - In your question your saying about *unexpected ad*. However it is not that straightforward how to deal with *unexpected* events on the site under test. So this code implies that you **expect** the banner will appear.

To make your test work with both cases when banner might appear and might not appear you can wrap `closeAd` method invocation with `try..catch` block and catch `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException`. In this case your test will anyway be hanging for a timeout period before proceed.

Comment: thank you very much. It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Please find the code**

```
public class PopUp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.letskodeit.com/");
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='style-joictyv2']")).click();

    }
```

Hope this is helpful.